# Difficulty mocking classes using python 'mock' (django)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'm using python's "mock" module to mock classes and functions in a django project.
The structure of my project is:

```
Project name --> 'hello'
               App1 ----> hello
               App2 ----> hello_world
               App3 ----> bye
```

'hello' contains just the **tests.py** and **settings.py**. 'hello_world' contains the views file **'greetings.py'** that goes like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest,HttpResponse
from bye import views

# Create your views here.                                                                                                                                                                                   

def greet(request):
    views.saybye()
    gb_class = views.goodbye()

    print gb_class.saygoodbye()
    print 'greet called'

    return HttpResponse('hello world',content_type='application/html')
```

'bye' contains '**views.py**' which contains:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.http import HttpRequest

# Create your views here.

def saybye():
    print "goodbye world"
    return

class goodbye:
    def __init__(self):
        print "goodbye's init called"
        return

    def saygoodbye(self):
        return "goodbye.saygoodbye called"
```

Now, my 'tests.py' is:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import mock
from mock import patch

from hello_world import greetings
import bye 

from django.test.client import RequestFactory


class TestBasic(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.var = 'abc'
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    @patch('bye.views.goodbye')
    def test_greeting(self,mocksaybye):
        assert mocksaybye is bye.views.goodbye
        mocksaybye.saygoodbye = mock.MagicMock(return_value="mocked goodbye called")

        bye.views.goodbye()
        print mocksaybye.saygoodbye()

        assert mocksaybye.called
        assert mocksaybye.saygoodbye.called

        req = self.factory.get('/sayhello/')
        greetings.greet(req)
```

I get the following output on running 'python manage.py test':

```
mocked goodbye called
goodbye world
<MagicMock name='goodbye().saygoodbye()' id='60566864'>
greet called
```

I expected the 3rd line of the output to be: `"mocked goodbye called"` as from what I understand, the **mocksaybye** class will mock goodbye class's saygoodbye function and return the custom output **mocked goodbye called**.

However, this does not happen. Why is it so? Also, what should I do to get this desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`side_effect`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) method, not [`return_value`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.return_value). And also [`@patch.object`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object) instead of [`@patch`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch)

So instead of this code:

```
@patch('bye.views.goodbye')
def test_greeting(self,mocksaybye):
    # ...
    mocksaybye.saygoodbye = mock.MagicMock(return_value="mocked goodbye called")
    # ...
```

Use this (have not tested):

```
@patch.object('bye.views.goodbye', 'saygoodbye')
def test_greeting(self,mocksaybye):
    # ...
    mocksaybye.side_effect = lambda: "mocked goodbye called"
    # ...
```

Comment: @nomad, have you tried the second solution from answer?

Comment: This answer is effectively the same as `return_value`. I think the issue is that you need to mock `greetings.views.goodbye` instead.

Comment: Also possible trouble: `goodbye` is an old style class, it is not inherited from `object`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser still doesn't work. The output is still the same.

Comment: @stalk none of the above solutions worked. The output is unaffected.

Comment: @nomad, try do declare your class like this: `class goodbye(object):`